# CSS automatically add a top margin

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to the front-end materials so bear with me
while I try to explain the question.

I'm having an issue trying to align three boxes together side by side.
However, when I try to add the `<p>` tag within the box, a top margin
gets added. Here is what I mean.

[image]

```
<div class="work-box">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="idea">
    </div>
     <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="idea">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="idea">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the boxes are wrapped within the "work-box" class. Here is the CSS code.

```
.work-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #495159;
  border: solid #A1E8CC thick;
}

.idea {
  height: 50%;
  background: url('img/idea.svg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

I have been struggling with this issue for this whole entire day and I just cannot figure it out. Please help!

Thank you so much.

Comment: use `vertical-align: top;` on `.box`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** Add `vertical-align: top` to your `.box` class.

**Explanation:** The effect that you saw was because for all `inline` elements, the `vertical-align` is defaulted to `baseline`.

This behaves funny when you have inline elements inside of your `.box`. Because it will try to align the last inline element to the `baseline` of all your inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `vertical-align:middle;` to the `box` class.

```
.box {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #495159;
  border: solid #A1E8CC thick;
}
```

[*See Codepen Example here*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwreBX) .

Answer (score 0):

You try using `<span>Hello world</span>` instead of `<p>` tag. Moreover, `<p>` tag is out of .idea div. Is it ok? I think it should be inside of `<div class="idea">`